# When does printf fail to print?

Tags: c, printf

printf function in c doesn't always print the output on screen. For example if you forget to put \n at the end of string you are printfing you sometimes don't get the o/p. Are there some other conditions when printf doesn't print. I remember someone saying that there are 7 such conditions. Can you guys please help.

Comment: Are you sure you're thinking of `printf`, and not the preconditions of the apocalypse?

Comment: @KerrekSB Or maybe the signs of an impending homework with 7 items ?

Comment: This seems platform specific, dependent on output device. What OS and system are you using?

Comment: Well, if the monitor is unplugged, if a meteor crashes into your computer, if a rabid weasel claws at the screen....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/469210

Comment: It may not print if you provide invalid format specifiers, or any other forms of undefined behaviour relating to `printf`.

Comment: The bit about the newline at the end is real enough, it happens because `stdout` is usually line-buffered... But 7 reasons? Why 7?

Comment: @JackManey, on some platforms, it will still print even with the rabid weasel. This problem is not cross-platform.

Comment: This smells like an upcoming test review question to me.

Comment: If an interrupt makes sufficient high-priority rabid weasels ready, and they insist on chasing their tails, the printf() may never complete.

Comment: printf() may be directed to attempt to print an unterminated weasel.

Comment: printf() may make a function call to return a parameter.  If this fails, an Eweasel exception may be raised.

Comment: Windows update may restart the box before the printf() can complete.

Comment: STDOUT may have been redirected, the network cable has fell out and the printf() blocks forever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Standard out is a buffered stream, it is not guaranteed to flush unless a newline is put in, the stream is closed, or the program exits normally.  If the program exits abnormally, it is possible for the stream to not flush.  Standard out is line buffered, which is why a newline will flush it.  There are buffers that will not flush with a newline.

Comment: I know that this is a very old question but what kind of thing can inhibit a `printf` of printing ?

Answer (score 10):

its not that `printf` won't always print, its that it isn't guaranteed to print immediately.  This means that if you are using it for debugging purposes, then you can't guarantee that it will happen exactly when it does in the code.  If you want to make sure that it does print exactly when you said it call 
`fflush(stdout)`.

**Note:**  You typically don't want to use `fflush(stdout)` unless you are debugging, its really resource intensive and if you care about speed performance at all it has the potential to slow you down.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
puts(largeString);
```

because in my particular case, *printf() just stopped printing* halfway through. The entire string was there, it just didn't print.

fflush(stdout) didn't fix it either, another printf() on the next line printed just fine.