# calculation of the length of the file doesn't work

Tags: c, file-io

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int noOfLines =0;
    char fname[]="Rtl_Prod_Id.txt";
    printf(fname);
    fp=fopen(fname,"r");
    char ch;

    //looping for every line
    do {
        ch=fgetc(fp);
        if (ch=='\n')
            noOfLines++;
    } while(ch!=EOF);

    //line before the last line
    if (ch!='\n'&&noOfLines!=0)
        noOfLines++;
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d",noOfLines);
    return 0;
}
```

I am just trying to calculate the number of lines in my file . The Same doesn't not return me any result .

What are the possible mistakes which i am doing

Environment : AIX and Compiler : CC

Thanks

**Edit : My program compiles succesfully but while execute the .Out file it doesn't turn up anything**

P.S :    *Although i got the answer . thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu .  I had change **char ch;**  to **int ch;** . but i wonder why ? What is wrong in char declaration ? . As i going to check for '\n' and EOF characters why integer then ?*

Comment: Is it literally not printing anything, or printing incorrect results? I get the correct number of lines + 1.

Comment: This part: `ch!='\n'` in last `if` is useless – the previous `do - while` terminates with `ch==EOF`, so in the `if` condition variable `ch` is `EOF` and never `\n`.

Comment: @merlin2011 : not printing anything

Comment: @CiaPan : the last condition i kept cos the last line will not be ended with a '\n'(newline) hence checking that .

Comment: Try adding a `\n` to the printf.  `printf("%d\n",noOfLines);` Maybe your OS doesn't flush stdout when the program terminates.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, you did verify that the filename is correct right?

Comment: @user3386109 : thanks for the suggestion , but tried that too . doesn't work .

Comment: code works fine. run it [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php) with input file as input.txt

Comment: The code works fine, any errors?

Comment: @all :  I got my desired output . but still wondering another question . kindly visit the P.S section of the question . thanks

Comment: May be the problem with buffers, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317529/when-does-printf-fail-to-print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild shot but changing the line

```
char ch;
```

to

```
int ch;
```

is appropriate. The return type of `fgetc` is `int`, not `char`.

Comment: @R Sahu : Well i think your wild shot worked for me . Would be wondering the reason why it works this way ? anyways thanks a ton .

Comment: @thinkinbee , this must help https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `char` on AIX is actually `unsigned char`.

`fgetc()` returns an `int` value and -1 is (typically) used to signal EOF. However, because `unsigned char` cannot be negative (EOF becomes 255), so the comparison `ch != EOF` will always be true and this causes an endless loop.

Defining `int ch;` fixes the problem; btw, this should have shown up during compilation if you use `-Wall` (show all compiler warnings).

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `<...>` instead of `"..."` to include system header files such as `stdio.h` or `stdlib.h`.
2. You should check the return value of `fopen` for possible error.
3. The return type of `fgetc()` is `int`, not `char`.
4. There is a logical flaw in your last line adaption. After the before `do {} while` loop, `ch` is EOF, it never will be `'\n'`. You need another flag to remember if there is any characters after the last `'\n'`, and set it properly in your `do {} while` loop.

Here is a fixed version of your code, a little more flexible:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int noOfLines, isRem, ch;

    if (argc > 1) {
        fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            perror("fopen");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else {
        fp = stdin;
    }

    noOfLines = 0;
    isRem = 0;

    //looping for every line
    do {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch != EOF)
            isRem = 1;
        if (ch == '\n') {
            noOfLines++;
            isRem = 0;
        }
    } while (ch != EOF);

    //line before the last line
    if (isRem)
        noOfLines++;

    if (argc > 1)
        fclose(fp);

    printf("%d\n", noOfLines);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

Testing:

```
$ wc -l t000.c 
44 t000.c
$ ./a.out t000.c 
44
$ echo -e "abc\ndef" | ./a.out 
2
$ echo -ne "abc\ndef" | ./a.out 
2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I had change char ch; to int ch; . but i wonder why ? What is wrong in
>   char declaration ? . As i going to check for '\n' and EOF characters
>   why integer then ?

EOF has a value of -1, and is of type INT, hence ch must be of type INT too.

Also, the prototype of getchar() is

```
int getchar(void);
```

so the return of getchar() must always be checked with an integer type.

There is an inherent confusion of EOF, read more about it [here](https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/)