# I use sleep function in ubuntu ,but printf function run very slowly in while loop. why?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I use ubuntu 14.04 version system for below code.
I use below code : (below code is infinite Loop)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int flag=0;

int main(void){

    printf("program start.\n");   
    printf("PID=%d\n",getpid());    
    printf("flag=%d\n",flag);
    //-----------I feel weired below do...while... sentences----------//
    do{
        printf("loop_");
        sleep(1);
       }while(flag==0);

    printf("program exit.\n");    
    return 0;
}
```

in the beginning below print result :

```
root@ubuntu:~/Desktop/my_test_code# ./issue 
program start.
PID=3113
flag=0
...........//start waiting here,and don't print "loop_"
```

then after I waited for long time this program  prints a lot of "loop_".
I find it very strange, and should print a string "loop_" and then, wait a second, then print a "loop_" again, and so on, why me waiting for a long time, do it start to print a lot of "loop_" ?

anybody has any idea for my issue . thank you in advance.

Comment: flushing output may help to have expected behavior.

Comment: Is this C or C++, and for Linux or Unix?

Comment: `printf` is line buffered. It will not flush to stdout until a newline is encountered. So either put a `"\n"` at the end of your print string or explicitly `fflush`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does printf fail to print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317529/when-does-printf-fail-to-print)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:**

Usually stdout's buffer are getting flushed by `\n` so here loop goes on and stdout did not get chance to buffered its data properly.

**Solution:**

There are three way here

1) Use `\n` at the end of printf

```
printf("loop_\n");
```

2) call `fflush(stdout):` after printf in loop.

3) Disabled the buffering for stdout stream using below call in your program

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

`printf` bufferizes its output (until a given size or `\n`), so you don't see the output until it flushes it.

changing your loop to

```
printf("loop_");
fflush(stdout);
sleep(1);
```

should solve your issue.